# PHP urldecode() - escaping "+" symbols

Tags: php, urldecode

I have this cookie which indicates 2 items split by **/**:

```
cookie packs = 10=BATTLEFIELD 2 + 1=20.00/10=BATTLEFIELD 2 + 1=20.00
$packs = explode("/", rawurldecode($_COOKIE["packs"]));
```

I need to decode it with `urldecode()`, but when I do it I lose the **+** sign between `BATTLEFIELD 2` and `1`, how can I avoid this?

Comment: split by / or /: ? What you're trying to do?

Comment: Split by "/" a cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of **`rawurldecode()`**. You won't lose the **+**

```
<?php
echo rawurldecode('10=BATTLEFIELD 2 + 1=20.00/10=BATTLEFIELD 2 + 1=20.00');
```

**OUTPUT:**

> 10=BATTLEFIELD 2 + 1=20.00/10=BATTLEFIELD 2 + 1=20.00

**EDIT :** [Since you changed the question]

```
<?php

$cookie_packs = '10=BATTLEFIELD 2 + 1=20.00/10=BATTLEFIELD 2 + 1=20.00';
$packs = explode("/", rawurldecode($cookie_packs));
var_dump($packs);

array (size=2)
  0 => string '10=BATTLEFIELD 2 + 1=20.00' (length=26)
  1 => string '10=BATTLEFIELD 2 + 1=20.00' (length=26)
```

Comment: Explain `It doesn't seem to work`. Seems like you are using PHP ver less than 3. Test the code here http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: Edited my question, packs outputs `BATTLEFIELD 2 1`